# How to encrypt/mask username and password ASP.NET web api C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, web

Can someone send me links where I can learn about how I can encrypt/mask the username and password sent to our server? Our VAPT results showed that the username and password are in clear text form (when they check the POST Request, the actual username and password is shown, the portion that is boxed in the image). I am really not sure how I can resolve this. you may refer to the image attached. thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you wonder about transport (which should be taken care of by HTTPS) or storage (you should not store the password at all, use salted hashes instead)?

Comment: `username and password are stored in cleartext form` where they are stored in clear text? If you are using any network traffic tracing tool, you can see the values passing between client and the server in plain text format. But in real time, the value being passed over the network are encrypted if the URL is https. That's the point of having using https.

Comment: hi @KlausGütter yes. i am not really sure how I can use https. i am really new to this, i am sorry if this is such a dumb question. do you have any links where i can study about using https?

Comment: hi @Chetan with VAPT results, it was returned that my username and password are being returned as plain text.. will using https resolve this concern? pls help.

Comment: What do the VAPT results say: "username and password are stored" (as in your question) or "username and password are being returned" (as in your last comment)?

Comment: the actual result only goes like: "the username and password is in cleartext form"

Comment: sorry, i will correct my post

Comment: Meh this particular test is useless. The credentials are already covered by TLS. Any further fudging client side is pointless because if an attacker can get inside TLS, they can just inject their own code to intercept the credential. Just find whatever lightweight encryption library to satisfy the test, but don't delude yourself thinking it add any actual security